# Print destructor in c++

Tags: c++, destructor

I have this code.The output is: ~A~A~AprintA~AprintA~AprintA~A. I understand why it prints out  printA~AprintA~AprintA~A(because I have 3 push_back) but I don't understant why "~A" appears 3 time at the beginning of the sentence.If I have just `v.push_back(a);` (just this ,without the other 2 push_backs),"~A",won't appear,why?

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
    class A {
    public:
        virtual void print() {
            std::cout << "printA";
        }
        virtual ~A() {
            std::cout << "~A";
        }
    };



int main() {
    std::vector<A> v;
    A a;
    A b;
    A c;
    v.push_back(a);
    v.push_back(b);
    v.push_back(c);
    for (auto e : v)
        e.print();

        }
```

Comment: Reallocation; making a copy in the loop.

Comment: Your question is badly formatted. Take a moment to fix that, please.

Comment: ...also your output formatting isnt the best. If you put a `"\n"` after each cout it would be much easier to read

Comment: The standard output is buffered : the string won't be displayed until you print a `\n` (or when the outuput buffer is full). If you don't do this, the printing order is not guaranteed, and you might have so problem like you have

Answer (score 2):

When you push back objects into the vector it's `size()` will increase. Then, when enough objects are added through `push_back()` (in this case only 1 was needed after the initial object) and `capacity() < size() + 1` becomes true the vector has to grow in capacity to be able to hold more elements, this requires reallocation and thus destruction and restruction of objects, this is why you're seeing the destructor calls.

Try increasing the capacity of the vector before adding to it by using `reserve(new_cap)` and you'll see that the destructor calls won't occur:

```
std::vector<A> v;
v.reserve(10);
A a;
A b;
A c;
//etc..
```

This didn't occur when you only pushed back 1 object because nothing was contained in the vector that had to be recreated.